# Error in seq.int(from, to, length.out = n) : 'from' must be a finite number

Tags: r

I keep getting this error  `"Error in seq.int(from, to, length.out = n) : 'from' must be a finite number."` I posted my code below.

```
 p <- seq(0, 1, .01)    
qnorm(p, mean=0, sd=1)
qcauchy(p, location = 0, scale = 1)
plot(qnorm, qcauchy, main = "Normal-Cauchy", xlab="normal", ylab = "cauchy")
```

Comment: urFum.png. alrighty. your code doesn't even mention what the error states so what are we supposed to do without knowing what "from" is

Comment: Welcome at SO! Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to store objects from `qnorm()` and `qcauchy()`. Try:

```
p <- seq(0, 1, .01)
q1 <- qnorm(p, mean = 0, sd = 1)
q2 <- qcauchy(p, location = 0, scale = 1)
plot(q1, q2, main = "Normal-Cauchy", xlab = "Normal", ylab = "Cauchy")
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked!

Comment: Hi @nghauran, when you have a moment, could you please take a look at my related question here? Thanks! »»» https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030888/gganimate-ggplot2-error-when-using-transition-time-after-transforming-dataset